# Adding Server Block Breaks Subdomains NGINX

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php

I currently have all HTTP connections redirecting to HTTPS using the following server block:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name _;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

This works very well. I also have a webapp running on a subdomain using the following server block:

```
    server {
            listen 443 ssl;
            server_name gitea.pyrosoftsolutions.co.uk;
            ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/gitea.pyrosoftsolutions.crt;
            ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/gitea.pyrosoftsolutions.key;
            ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
            ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';
            ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
            ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/dhparam/gitea.dhparam.pem;
            proxy_cookie_domain ~(?P<secure_domain>([-0-9a-z]+\.)?[-0-9a-z]+\.[a-z]+)$ "$secure_domain; sec$
            location / {
                    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" always;
                    add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inlin$
                    add_header X-Xss-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
                    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
                    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
            }
    }
```

Which again, seems to work fine. However, I want to run a website on the default/www domains. The problem arises when I enable the following server block:

```
server {
        listen   443 ssl;
        server_name pyrosoftsolutions.co.uk www.pyrosoftsolutions.co.uk;
        root /var/www/pyrosoftsolutions.co.uk;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root /var/www/pyrosoftsolutions.co.uk;
        }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php7.0-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
}
```

For some reason, when this block gets enabled, I can no longer access my subdomain, nor can I access any of the files/pages in the root directory. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what the full configuration is, but seems to me that you need `ssl_*` directives in the problematic block.

Defining the `SSL_CERTIFICATE` and `SSL_CERTIFICATE_KEY` directives should solve your issues. It is not possible for nginx to serve `HTTPS` pages without a suitable certificate defined.